# get_the_terms - only top level

Tags: php, functions, custom-taxonomy, terms

This code works good:

```
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'my_taxonomy');
if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $name = $term->name;
        $link = add_query_arg('fwp_typ', FWP()->helper->safe_value($term->slug), 'https://www.freuciv.com/');
        echo "<a href='$link'>$name</a><br />";
    }
}
```

It generates:

- Term1 (first level - parent)
- Term2 (second level - child)

I would like to get only the first level terms. How to modify it?

Comment: Untested guess: put `if ($term->parent) continue;` at the top of the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a quick test and seems both methods working well.

```
// @Rup's method
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'my_taxonomy');
if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      // skip if parent > 0
      if( $term->parent )
            continue;

        $name = $term->name;
        $link = add_query_arg('fwp_typ', FWP()->helper->safe_value($term->slug), 'https://www.freuciv.com/');
        echo "<a href='$link'>$name</a><br />";
    }
}
```

or

```
$terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'my_taxonomy');
if (!is_wp_error($terms) && !empty($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      // only do if parent is 0 (top most)
      if( $term->parent == 0 ) {
        $name = $term->name;
        $link = add_query_arg('fwp_typ', FWP()->helper->safe_value($term->slug), 'https://www.freuciv.com/');
        echo "<a href='$link'>$name</a><br />";
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, both methods working well. Thanks a lot! I'm very grateful for your help.